# How to resolve WSL2 port conflict with windows services?

Tags: windows-10, port, windows-subsystem-for-linux, services, pxe

I am on Windows 10 20H2 (Build 19042.867). I also using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Recently, after upgrading to SSD, I have a problem entering WSL2 with the following error:

```
wsl error 0xfffffff
press any key to continue
```

I searched the web and found that the problem back to another process working on Port 53 by using
`netstat -aon | findstr '53'`. Using `tasklist` I found a process with PID `3868` is using the port.
`tasklist` shows that it is `PxeService.exe`.
How can I resolve this conflict?

Comment: I would try the following solution [here](https://cynicalsys.com/2020/08/25/wsl2-error-0xffffffff/) would not trust the SO solution

Comment: `PxeService.exe` could apparently be included in [several different apps](http://processchecker.com/file/PXEService.exe.html).  If you just migrated to a SDD, I might guess that you used an EaseUS product listed there?  You might try uninstalling that app temporarily.